Best way to signal from (pure) native code via C++/CLI to (pure) managed code?
I would like to trigger a function call in (pure) managed code, whenever a certain trigger is received in native code. I do not specifically a specific kind of trigger, it can be a callback, virtual method override, signal, event, or something along those lines...
My software stack is a large native code base in C++, then a thin C++/CLI wrapper, and finally a C# application with WPF GUI. I can edit the full software stack. The C++ code base is event-driven using signals/slots, like libevent or Qt employ them. Now, consider a C++ slot viewUpdateRequested() that should trigger a re-rendering in the C# WPF GUI.
I found that I can get a trigger from C++/CLI to C#, by creating an event handler in C++/CLI, that C# can subscribe to. Then I can trigger the event in C++/CLI, and even pass some arguments. However, that gets me only half the way, from C++/CLI upwards in the software stack. I still need to go from native to C++/CLI.
I'm under the impression that in pure native code, I can not emit a C# event, because that would require compiling with /clr, and that in turn makes the class a shallow dummy that can not hold any native members, which finally breaks my signal/slot implementation. Am I somehow missing something here?
I did find some way to go from native code to C++/CLI, by passing a function pointer from C++/CLI to native code. But this leads to the following code stack, that looks ugly to me:
native code -(function pointer)-> C++/CLI -(event handler)-> C#/WPF

So what are my options to get the event or trigger all the way from pure native code all the way to C#?
Is there something I'm overlooking? What would be a "clean design" solution?

Just spitballing, if i'd were to put this together with Qt: Create a QObject to receive signals, add a CLI Class member from your a wrapper lib. Use PIMPL in your wrapper to keep the CLI stuff out of the header and be able to use it from native. Use the wrapped CLI to create C# events, and call that whole thing from the QObjects slots. Would that do what you need ?

Dear @nick, basically you are on the track of what I would like to achieve. But practically, how would the event transfer from the Qt slot in the wrapped PIMPL implementation to C#? The wrapped class does not see the wrapper, and can not call into it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451546/c-cli-managed-class-to-c-sharp-events/5451917#5451917

A 'trigger" can be a file in a folder or a message in a queue. Not enough information.

It was some time ago I coded c++/cli, and even longer since I coded pure c++. But assuming your c++/cli project references your native project you should be able to do something like this.

Create an abstract class in your c++ project, something like

class MyNativeInterface{
public: 
    virtual void RaiseEvent() = 0;


Implement this class in your C++/Cli project, that just forward the call to a managed interface:

public interface class IMyManagedInterface{
    void RaiseEvent();
}

class MyNativeClass : MyNativeInterface{
    gcroot<IMyManagedInterface^> managed;
public:
    MyNativeClass(IMyManagedInterface^ managedReference){
        managed = managedReference;
    }
    void RaiseEvent(){
        managed->RaiseEvent();
    }
}


The c# side could look something like this:

public class MyManagedClass : IMyManagedInterface{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent ;
    public void RaiseEvent()=> MyEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

The difficult part is often how to create/connect all the objects to each other, but this depends on your overall architecture.

because that would require compiling with /clr, and that in turn makes the class a shallow dummy that can not hold any native members, which finally breaks my signal/slot implementation.

I'm not really a c++/cli expert, but I was able to turn on the /clr flag for some c++ projects with no or minimal changes. This allows both managed (ref) classes to hold pointers to native classes and native classes to hold references to managed classes (with gcroot<>). In my experience it made interop quite a bit easier compared to our original plan with a separate c++/cli interop layer. But our goal was to migrate to C#, so the .Net dependency was not a problem. I don't know what you mean by "shallow dummy", nor your "signal/slot implementation", but it might be worth an hour or two just trying to turn on the flag and see if things break.

In your answer, do I understand correctly that the C++/CLI class inherits from the C++ native class? I think this is not possible, or at least Hans Passant says so in a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981835/7200132.

@emmenlau a managed class (i.e. ref class) cannot inherit from a native class, but MyNativeClass is just regular, native, c++ class, so that can inherit just fine. It just needs to have /clr support so it can contain a gcroot to refer to a managed class.

Now I understand! This is very clever, actually! It very well suits my use case. To make your answer fully complete, could you kindly add how the gcroot member managed is initialized in MyNativeClass? I understand that the managed class needs to set this somehow, correct?

@emmenlau I added a constructor, but Its difficult to provide a complete example, since initialization will depend on your particular architecture. But generally you need an additional managed class in your C++/CLI project that can be called from the C# side, and is responsible for creating MyNativeClass, and any other native objects.
